# How to convert 4D generted data from excelsheet to OPL CPLEX Form?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a 4d array say `Array4D[i in rangeA][j in rangeB][k in rangeC][l in rangeD]=...;` I want to read its data from an excel sheet. How could I do this? I have checked the previously answered question-- in that given link is not working and the method presented gave an error as `IBM ILOG Concert: excel: range size is not the size of tupleSet.`
In my problem rangeA = 1; rangeB is 20, rangeC is 40 and rangeD is 100.

Answer (score 0):

In this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)

[image]

see [Read 3 dimension arrays](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read3Darray.dat)

.mod

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;


tuple someTuple{
    key int a;
    key int b;
    key int c;
    int value;
    };
    

{someTuple} someSet = ...;

int v[a in A][b in B][c in C]=item(someSet,<a,b,c>).value;

dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
    forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==v[a][b][c];
}


assert forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("write3Darray.xlsx");

someSet from SheetRead(sheet,"A1:D24");
```